# HTML problem: cannot find variables in a function

Tags: html, typescript

So I'm trying to make a simple CRUD system but running into a problem. More specifically, I'm making a webpage that can add and delete entries but when I try to run the webpage it shows some errors notifying that some variables can't be accessed or not defined. I know this is due to the variable being in a local function. Any tips on how to fix this? Here's the HTML and TypeScript code:

```js
import * as ko from "knockout";

class People {
  id: KnockoutObservable < number > ;
  name: KnockoutObservable < string > ;
  age: KnockoutObservable < number > ;

  constructor(name: string, age: number, id: number) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
  }

  addEntry = function() {
    let self = this;
    this.entryInfo = ko.observableArray([
      new People("Long", 23, 36457547),
      new People("TD", 23, 43635736)
    ]);

    this.removeEntry = function(entry: People) {
      this.entryInfo.remove(entry);
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new People("Long", 23, 3234234));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="./externals/require.js"></script>
<script src="./built/require-config.js"></script>
<script>
  require(["built/hello"]);
</script>

<h2>Employee Information (<span data-bind="text: entryInfo().length"></span>)</h2>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: entryInfo">
      <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: id" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: age" /></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeEntry">Remove Entry</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button data-bind="click: addEntry">Add Entry</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcS4z.png)